# Value of EditText in ListView duplicate itself every fourth row

Tags: android, listview

I have `ListView` that has a an `EditText` in every row.When i enter the value in the `EditText`  it duplicate itself in every fourth row in the `ListView` . How can I prevent that.

```
    public class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items>{


    Double Price;
    Double Quantity;
    String  _Quantity;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    Items items;


    public ItemsAdapter(Context ctx, int resourceId, List<Items> objects){

        super( ctx, resourceId, objects );
        resource = resourceId;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( ctx );
        context=ctx;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

        ItemViewHolder viewHolder;
        items = getItem( position );

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder=new ItemViewHolder();
            convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

   viewHolder.txtQuantity  =(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
            viewHolder.lblItemsName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblItemName);
            viewHolder.lblPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblPrice);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.lblItemsName.setText(items.getItemName());
        viewHolder.lblPrice.setText(items.getPrice().toString());

        return convertView;
    }


  public class ItemViewHolder {

    public EditText txtQuantity ;
    public TextView lblItemsName;
    public TextView lblPrice;

    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out

```
  public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<Cart> productList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, productList);
            this.productList = new ArrayList<Cart>();
            this.productList.addAll(productList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.productList.size();
        };
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");

       //     productList=   DBAdapter.getCartList();
            final     Cart product = productList.get(position);



            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_cart, null);


                EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);


                //attach the TextWatcher listener to the EditText
                quantity.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(view));

            }


            TextView   ItemNumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemNumber);
            ItemNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            EditText quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
            quantity.setTag(product);
            if(product.getQuantity() != 0){
                quantity.setText(String.valueOf(product.getQuantity()));
            }
            else {
                quantity.setText("1");
            }

            TextView itemNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemNumber);
            itemNumber.setText(product.getItemNumber());
            TextView ItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblItemName);
            ItemName.setText(product.getItemName());
            TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblPrice);
            price.setText( df.format(product.getPrice()));
            TextView ext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTotal);
            if(product.getQuantity() != 0){
                ext.setText("$" + df.format(product.getTotal()));
            }
            else {
                ext.setText("");
            }






            return view;

        }

    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;
        private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //do nothing
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //do nothing
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
            String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
            int quantity = qtyString.equals("") ? 0:Integer.valueOf(qtyString);

            EditText qtyView = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
            Cart product = (Cart) qtyView.getTag();

            if(product.getQuantity() != quantity){

                Double currPrice = product.getTotal();
                Double extPrice = quantity * product.getPrice();
                Double priceDiff = Double.valueOf(df.format(extPrice - currPrice));

                product.setQuantity(quantity);
                product.setTotal(extPrice);

                TextView ext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTotal);
                if(product.getQuantity() != 0){
                    ext.setText("$" + df.format(product.getTotal()));
                }
                else {
                    ext.setText("");
                }

                if(product.getQuantity() != 0){
                    qtyView.setText(String.valueOf(product.getQuantity()));
                }
                else {
                    qtyView.setText("");
                }

                orderTotal += priceDiff;
                TextView cartTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cartTotal);
                cartTotal.setText(df.format(orderTotal));

            }

            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start enter the quantity in each cell of `ListView`, you should save the quantity to the `items`
After that, you load the quantity from `item`

```
    ... your above code
    }

        viewHolder.txtQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        items.setQuantity(s); // set quantity for each item when you enter quantity
                }
            });

    viewHolder.lblItemsName.setText(items.getItemName());
    viewHolder.lblPrice.setText(items.getPrice().toString());

    viewHolder.txtQuantity.setText(items.getQuantity()); // load quantity for each item
   ...
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

The duplication happens because views are recycled in `Listview` when you scroll. To avoid this you should reset the text in `Edittext` in `getView()` method.

If you want to retain the text in `EditText` when you come back to the view again you should do something like Phan Văn Linh suggested.